# Issues with Doctrine 2 Mappings Yaml

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, doctrine-orm, yaml

I am trying to get these mappings right but I just cannot seem to and would love some advice...

```
Entities\User:
  type: entity
  oneToMany:
    citations:
      targetEntity: Citation
      mappedBy: user
      cascade: ["all"]

Entities\Citation:
  type: entity
  manyToOne:
    item:
      targetEntity: Item
      inversedBy: citations
      joinColumn:
        name: item_id
        referencedColumnName: id
  manyToOne:
    user:
      targetEntity: User
      inversedBy: citations
      joinColumn:
        name: user_id
        referencedColumnName: id


Entities\Item:
  type: entity
  oneToMany:
    authors:
      targetEntity: Author
      mappedBy: item
      cascade: ["all"]
  oneToMany:
    citations:
      targetEntity: Citation
      mappedBy: item


Entities\Author:
  type: entity
  manyToOne:
    item:
      targetEntity: Item
      inversedBy: authors
```

The errors I get from the schema validator tool are:

> [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Entities\Item' mapping is invalid:
>   * The association Entities\Item#citations refers to the owning side field Entities\Citation#item which does not exist.
>
> [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Entities\Citation' mapping is invalid:
>   * The association Entities\Citation#user refers to the inverse side field Entities\User#citations which does not exist.
>
> [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Entities\Author' mapping is invalid:
>   * The association Entities\Author#item refers to the inverse side field Entities\Item#authors which does not exist.

As you can see I have the inverse sides, why is it not seeing them?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the related properties on the classes (in the php files) ?

ie: Does Entities\Citation has an item property ? .. `property $item;`

Comment: No it does not, it was skipped by the the orm:generate-entities command, which made me think that the mapping was incorrect. :(

Comment: I thought it could be a naming conflict having two associations on an entity be mapped by the same keyword, e.g. in the Item Entity both Citations and Authors being mappedby Item. But I made them unique and it had no effect.